# Unable to call function in ajax success

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

```
$('.handleObject').on("change", function() {
        var id = $(this).val();
        var cid = $('#cid').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/example/shirt/listing',
            data: {
                id: id,
                cid: cid
            },
            success: function(){
                  resetOptionValues('collarAround', collarAround); /**Getting error for this**/
            }
        });

});
```

Comment: What the error say ? And where collarAround variable is defined ?